# Explicación función one line

Tags: javascript

No termino de entender porque estas lineas de código retornan lo que retornar, pongo ejemplos

```js
v1 = (true && "juan") // juan
v2 = (false && "juan") // false
v3 = ("pedro" && "juan") // juan

console.log("v1:", v1)
console.log("v2:", v2)
console.log("v3:", v3)
```

Me gustaria saber que son y más sobre este tipo de funciones y si es posible algún ejemplo más ya que parece que tienen bastante potencial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En Javascript la sentencia && es un [operador lógico AND](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Operadores_l%C3%B3gicos).

Por definición:

> `expr1 && expr2`: Regresa expr1 si tal puede convertirse a false; de lo contrario, regresa expr2. De esta forma, cuando se usa con valores Boolean, && regresa true si ambos operandos son verdaderos; de lo contrario regresa false.

En tus casos:

`true && "juan"`

- la primera expresión no puede igualarse a false por lo que devuelve la segunda expresión, juan

`false && "juan"`

- la primera expresión sí puede igualarse a false por lo que es la que devuelve

`"pedro" && "juan"`

- misma situación que el primer caso: la primera expresión no puede igualarse a false por lo que devuelve la segunda expresión, juan

Comment: Falta comentar que JavaScript convierte los string a booleanos. Cualquier string que no esté vacío se evalúa como `true`.